# Hide column in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, hide

How can we show/hide some columns in JTable?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend JXTable from the [SwingX project](https://swingx.dev.java.net/), hiding columns in the view is very easy:

```
table.getColumnExt(index).setVisible(false);
```

JXTable also provides a column control(menu in top-right corner) where user by them selfs can hide/show columns.

Answer (score 1):

When using JXTable from the SwingX project, as suggested by Uhlen,
It's better to use
`table.getColumnExt("columnName").setVisible(true);`
`table.getColumnExt("columnName").setVisible(false);`

the index when using `getColumnExt(index)`is the column index that is **in the view** (i.e.visible)
Once you set a column invisible, you can't access to it by `getColumnExt(index)`

Comment: how do you know if the column is not visible?

Comment: table.getColumnExt("columnName").isVisible() should work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having to loop through the list for every cell call as shown at codeGuru, you could change the columnModel to switch the column-visibility by setting from/to zero-width and setting editable/noneditable. That wat default handling skips over that column.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a sample at codeguru:

- http://www.codeguru.com/java/articles/660.shtml

Don't forget that google is your best friend ...